# How to automate unlocking the screen on android for testing?

Tags: android, command-line, automated-tests, rooted-device

I need to run some automated tests on an android device, the problem is that the screen needs to be unlocked first. I have tried:

```
input keyevent KEYCODE_MENU
```

But this hasn't worked.

I have access to a rooted device for this purpose and have removed the password. Just need a way to unlock the screen.

Comment: not possible. You can not lock access menu button through code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set your lock screen to none, you just need to send a power on command using adb.

```
# Switches on the android devices screen if it isn’t already on.
if `adb shell dumpsys input_method | grep mInteractive`.include? 'false'
  `adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_POWER`
end

# Pre lollipop devices respond to this command a bit differently.
if `adb shell dumpsys input_method | grep mScreenOn`.include? 'false'
  `adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_POWER`
end
```

The above will press the power button if the screen isn't already on.